# Best practices for high performance input pipeline using only tf.data API (no feed_dict)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

The official TensorFlow [Performance Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide) states the following:

> While feeding data using a feed_dict offers a high level of
>   flexibility, in general feed_dict does not provide a scalable
>   solution. If only a single GPU is used, the difference between the
>   tf.data API and feed_dict performance may be negligible. Our
>   recommendation is to avoid using feed_dict for all but trivial
>   examples. In particular, avoid using feed_dict with large inputs.

However, avoiding the use of **feed_dict** entirely appears to be impossible. Consider the following setup with train, validation, and test datasets.

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset
n_files = 1000 # total number of tfrecord files
split = int(.67 * n_files)
files = ds.zip((ds.range(n_files),ds.list_files("train/part-r-*")))
train_files = files.filter(lambda a, b: a < split).map(lambda a,b: b)
validation_files = files.filter(lambda a, b: a >= split).map(lambda a,b: b)
test_files = ds.list_files("test/part-r-*")
```

A common method to parse the datasets might look like the following:

```
def setup_dataset(self, file_ds, mode="train"):

   data = file_ds.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(
       tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
       cycle_length=4,
       sloppy=True,
       buffer_output_elements=self.batch_size * 8,
       prefetch_input_elements=self.batch_size * 8
   ))

   if mode == "train":
       data = data.map(self.train_data_parser)
   else:
       data = data.map(self.test_data_parser)

   return data
```

Then instead of feeding the individual features through a **feed_dict** in `session.run()`, you would create a reusable iterator with either `Iterator.from_structure()` or `Iterator.from_string_handle()`. I will show an example with the former, but you run into the same problem either way.

```
train = self.setup_dataset(train_files)
self.ops["template_iterator"] = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train.output_types, train.output_shapes)
self.ops["next_batch"] = self.ops["template_iterator"].get_next(name="next_batch")
self.ops["train_init"] = self.ops["template_iterator"].make_initializer(train)

validation = self.setup_dataset(validation_files)
self.ops["validation_init"] = self.ops["template_iterator"].make_initializer(validation)
```

This all works great, but what am I supposed to do with the test dataset? The test dataset will not contain the label feature(s) and therefore not conform to the same **output_types** and **output_shapes** as the train and validation datasets.

I would ideally like to restore from a SavedModel and initialize the test dataset rather than serve the model over an API.

What is the trick that I am missing to incorporate test dataset during inference?

Answer (score 0):

I have my datasets and iterators set up for training and inference like this:

```
# Train dataset
images_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, train_images.shape)
labels_train = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, train_masks.shape)
dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"images": images_train, "masks": labels_train})
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(MINIBATCH)
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(lambda x: map_helper(x, augmentation), num_parallel_calls=8)
dataset_train = dataset_train.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

iterator_train = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset_train.output_types, dataset_train.output_shapes)
training_init_op = iterator_train.make_initializer(dataset_train)
batch_train = iterator_train.get_next()

# Inference dataset
images_infer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None] + list(valid_images.shape[1:]))
labels_infer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None] + list(valid_masks.shape[1:]))
dataset_infer = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({"images": images_infer, "masks": labels_infer})
dataset_infer = dataset_infer.batch(MINIBATCH)

iterator_infer = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset_infer.output_types, dataset_infer.output_shapes)
infer_init_op = iterator_infer.make_initializer(dataset_infer)
batch_infer = iterator_infer.get_next()
```

## Training

Initialise the iterator for training using `training_init_op`

```
sess.run(training_init_op, feed_dict={images_train: train_images, labels_train: train_masks})
```

## Validation

Initialise the inference iterator for validation using `infer_init_op`

```
sess.run(infer_init_op, feed_dict={images_infer: images_val, labels_infer: masks_val})
```

## Test

Initialise the inference iterator for testing using `infer_init_op`. This is a bit hacky, but I create an array with zeros where the labels would go and use the same iterator I used for validation

```
sess.run(infer_init_op, feed_dict={images_infer: images_test, labels_infer: np.zeros(images_test.shape)})
```

Alternatively, you could create 3 different dataset/iterators for train/validation/test

Comment: I thought of doing something like by using `dataset.map()` to insert a fake label of the same shape. However, like you said, this seemed a bit hacky and perhaps not the most maintainable way to create an input pipeline that might possibly contain multiple labels in a multi-task situation.